# .Equals returning unexpected result

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Please see the code below:

```
public class ValueType<T> where T : class,new()
    {
        public virtual bool Equals(T other)
        {
            if (other == null)
                return false;
            Type t = GetType();
            Type otherType = other.GetType();
            if (t != otherType)
                return false;
            FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
            foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
            {
                object value1 = field.GetValue(other);
                object value2 = field.GetValue(this);
                if (value1 == null)
                {
                    if (value2 != null)
                        return false;
                }
                else if (!value1.Equals(value2))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    class Tiger : ValueType<Tiger> { public string name; public Tiger mother; }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tiger t1 = new Tiger() { name = "Teri" }; 
            Tiger t2 = new Tiger() { name = "Teri" }; 
            Tiger t3 = new Tiger() { name = "Toni", mother=t1 };
            Tiger t4 = new Tiger() { name = "Toni", mother = t2 };
            bool Test1 = t4.mother.Equals(t3.mother); //Highlighed line
            bool Test2 = t4.Equals(t3);
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why the highlighted line returns false.  I would expect it to run in an infinate loop.

Comment: Why you expect an infinite loop? It returns `true` btw. Isn't that expected becaue both mothers are equal, they have the same name and no mother. Their `mother` field returns `null` since the `Tiger` is a refernce type(class):

Comment: I think he is expecting !value1.Equals(value2) to call the same equals function

Comment: @ chrispepper1989, yes.  +1.

Comment: have you checked its calling your equals function, you havent put "new" or "override" so it might be calling the standard equals

Comment: Only a few tips: implement `override Equals(object obj)`, add interface `IEquatable<T>` _(since you already implement this)_, use `ReferenceEquals` as first compare to do not cause unnecessary evaluating of `Equals` of identical mother instances.

Comment: btw it does call the first time, but the second time it does not call your override

Comment: @chrispepper1989: well, the `mother` is null so it never comes to the `else if` on the mother field

Comment: @TimSchmelter true, I assumed he was expecting the test2 to infinite loop, the test1 equals definitely wouldnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you expect an infinite loop? Following returns `true` not `false`:

```
bool Test1 = t4.mother.Equals(t3.mother); .
```

Isn't that expected because both mothers are equal? They have the same `name` and there's no "grandmom". Their `mother` field returns `null` since the `Tiger` is a reference type(class).

> Why  `t4.Equals(t3)` returns `false`?

Because you have declared it as `Object`, so `Object.Equals` is used which just compares references. If you would try-cast it to `Tiger` this `Equals` would be called.

That's why this doesn't cause an infinite loop but just returns `false`(not the same reference):

```
...else if (!value1.Equals(value2))
```

Note that you haven't overridden `Equals`. You would get your expected behaviour if you'd do it:

```
class Tiger : ValueType<Tiger> {
    public string name; public Tiger mother;
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return ((ValueType<Tiger>) obj).Equals(this);
    }
}
```

Now this works as expected. It won't cause an infinite recursion because at some time the parent `mother` will be `null`, but it will check recursively if also the mothers are equal.

Another way would be to change the signature of the already existing `Equals` in `ValueType`:

```
public override bool Equals(Object other)
```

Comment: By t4.Equals(t3) returns false?

Comment: @w0051977: because the fields are declared as `Object`, so `Object.ReferenceEquals` will be used. You have't overridden `Equals`. I have edited my answer

Comment: Sorry.  I was expecting the second call to .Equals to call the generic method.  That is why I expected an infinite loop.  I see what is happening now.

Comment: Just as an extra point if you had set t1s mother to t4 and/or t2's mother to t3 you would get an infinite recursive loop so something to be careful of :)